# Cannot compile GPD in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: path, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, ros, catkin

I cannot compile gpd in Ubuntu 14.04, I compiled it before but no luck this time. When I tried to compile, I keep getting this error:

**In file included from /home/tawfiq/catkin_ws/src/gpd/src/gpd/caffe_classifier.cpp:1:0:
/home/tawfiq/catkin_ws/src/gpd/src/gpd/../../include/gpd/caffe_classifier.h:41:27: fatal error: caffe/caffe.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "caffe/caffe.hpp"**

The following lines are already in caffe_classifier.h file:

```
// Caffe
#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"
#include "caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/util/io.hpp"
```

In caffe classifier.cpp file which is inside the gpd folder in my catkin_ws src directory, the following line is included:

```
#include "../../include/gpd/caffe_classifier.h"
```

The caffe folder is in home, inside caffe folder, there is include folder, then caffe folder, then caffe.hpp in caffe.

It is working fine in others' computers. I installed cuda 7.5. Then caffe and gpd from this link:

https://github.com/atenpas/gpd

and followed what they said. Cuda and caffe successfully compiled. It is so frustrating, I tried updating the bashrc or putting the absolute path in caffe folder, nothing worked.

Comment: Did You Add the include path to CMakeLists.txt ?? Can you add your cmakelists.txt to the post ?

Comment: I found the solution, the caffe needs to be compiled with cmake, not.